# Chrome Extension: Button in extension is supposed to open a webpage, but return a page in the chrome extension. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple Chrome extension where the user selects a button and opens a new browser page to a randomly selected website (e.g. Stumble Upon or Cloudhiker). However, when on click, a new browser page opens but it says it's specific to the extension and the intended URL is prepended with chrome extension data. For example: chrome-extension://hflifofppgknepfodmmkohenjknmendb/www.bing.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stumble Upon Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: grey;
}
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const title = document.createElement('h1');
  title.innerText = 'Welcome to the Stumble Upon Clone!';
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(title);

  const btnStumble = document.createElement('button');
  btnStumble.setAttribute('class', 'btnStumble');
  btnStumble.innerText = "Let's Stumble!";
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(btnStumble);

  btnStumble.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const selection = randomSite();
    console.log(selection);
    window.open(selection);
  });
});

const sites = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.bing.com'];

const randomSite = () => {
  const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  const choice = sites[roll];
  return choice;
};

randomSite(sites);
randomSite(sites);
randomSite(sites);
```

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "Stumble Upon Clone",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "My version of the old Stumble Upon website",
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
      },
      "icons": {
        "48": "img/cloud.png"
      }
    }
```

I've tried changing the window.open to document.open, but that wasn't helpful. I'm not sure what else to do at this point. Thank you for any help and insight you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Add "https://" or "http://" to the URLs in `sites` and it should work.

The slightly longer answer is: If you call `window.open()` you can either provide a relative or an absolute URL. If you want to provide an absolute URL, you need to add the URL scheme (i.e., "https://" or "http://") so that it recognizes it as an absolute URL. Without, `window.open()` assumes that the given URL is relative and will add it relative to the current URL, which is the URL of the extension as you are open it from the extension's popup page.